# Why perceptron is linear classifier?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, linear, perceptron

It is said that perceptron is linear classifier, but it has a non-linear activation function f = 1 if wx - b >= 0 and f = 0 otherwise

If i will use some non-linear function on linear combination of my data, i think i will get a non-linear classifier. Why it is false?

Answer (score 1):

It is called a linear classifier because its decision boundary is given by a (linear) hyperplane. Such a hyperplane is given by the set $\{ x | w^tx =b \}$ which thus splits $\mathbf R^n$ into two classes, $\{x | w^tx \leq b\}$ and $\{ x | w^tx > b\}$. You can think of $w$ as the normal vector to this hyperplane and $b$ as an offset by which you shift the hyperplane.

Comment: Is a last layer of neural network a linear classifier?

Comment: That depends on your neural network, in general that does not have to be the case.

Comment: The hyperplane comment is the correct reason, but the first one isn't sufficient and may not lead to linear classification for certain activation functions

Comment: @gunes: I think that depends on your definition of "linear classifier". Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier) defines a linear classifier as a classifier that makes "decision[s] based on the value of a linear combination" of your data.

Comment: Can i consider a last layer of neurons a linear classifier relatively of inputs to the last neurons?

Comment: But if the decision boundary is not flat, the classifier is not a linear classifier. The statement of wiki is correct since it states that linear classifiers operate on linear combination of the data features. For example, if the decision function is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      1 & 0<x<1 \\
      0 & 1\leq x 
\end{cases}$$ , the decision boundary will not be a hyperplane.

Comment: @gunes: I see your point, to me the wikipedia article is ambiguous, i.e. it does not rigorously define what a linear classifier is. Having looked up a more reliable source (Wasserman's All of Statistics) I'll agree with you that the correct definition of a linear classifier is "a classifier such that the decision boundary is a hyperplane" and not "a classifier that only depends on a linear combination of the inputs". I'll edit my post accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

The activation function of a perceptron is **linear in it's parameters**, i.e. the decision boundary is defined by a linear function of the form $w^tx = b$ = $\sum_{i} w_{i} * x_{i}$.

Similar to linear least squares, the perceptron does not care whether the input $x_{i}$'s are non-linear combinations of your original data. You can indeed model a non-linear decision boundary using a polynomial basis function, e.g. if your data consist of a single independent variable $x$ you could include the square of $x$ as an additional variable.

Again, the perceptron can only model a linear decision boundary, but linear decision boundaries in quadratic space become a non-linear curve when mapped back to the original space.

Comment: I dont think this answers this question correctly. While the sumproduct is calculated with linear function, the activation is a nonlinear function (like Sigmoid, ReLU , tan() and others) , so, since sigmoid is the output and it is nonlinear, then the perceptron , even if it is a single one becomes a nonlinear function. If you are saying that perceptron is linear, then show a proof.

Comment: @Nulik You have a point, but I'm convinced that as long as the activation function is monotonic, choosing a threshold on the activation will lead to the input being separated by a single hyperplane, as there is a bijective mapping between the outputs of the linear model and the non-linear activation. However, if the activation is non-monotonic (I tried this using the activation f(x) = abs(x)), there is a surjective-only mapping of the linear outputs onto the activations, so there are two (or more?) separating hyperplanes in input space, which I'd say would be a non-linear classifier.

Comment: @Nulik In any case, all separating lines are **linear** hyperplanes.